# Better approach to doing ifelse by group

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, data.table

I have dataset with ID, Weight, Date, Status and Baseline column as follows

```
  Id     Weight     Date         Status     Baseline
  5      121.23     04/16/1995   No         NA
  5      134.12     12/17/2008   No         NA
  5      167.63     03/15/2002   No         NA
  5      139.22     08/15/2001   No         NA
  23     232.19     11/10/2009   Yes        11/06/2001
  23     274.13     10/03/2004   Yes        11/06/2001
  23     134.23     07/11/2006   Yes        11/06/2001
```

If status is No, then I want the **new column** *Recent_Weight* to store the weight closest to the SysDate () for that Id. If status is Yes, then I want the *Recent_Weight* to be the the weight closest to the date in the Baseline column.

```
  Id     Weight     Date         Status     Baseline      Recent_Weight
  5      121.23     04/16/1995   No         NA            134.12 
  5      134.12     12/17/2008   No         NA            134.12  
  5      167.63     03/15/2002   No         NA            134.12
  5      139.22     08/15/2001   No         NA            134.12
  23     232.19     11/10/2009   Yes        11/06/2001    274.13    
  23     274.13     10/03/2004   Yes        11/06/2001    274.13
  23     134.23     07/11/2006   Yes        11/06/2001    274.13
```

Right now I am doing this using mutate and group_by as follows

```
library(dplyr)
Test2 %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  mutate(New_Weight = ifelse(Status== "No",   
  as.numeric(Weight[which.min(abs(Sys.Date() - Date))]), 
  as.numeric(Weight[which.min(abs(Baseline   - Date))])))
```

However I get very inconsistent results. I have to shutdown and restart everytime or else I get wrong answers(I know this is very strange). I am wondering if anybody can suggest me a better way to obtain the same results. Thanks y'all.I appreciate your time.

Comment: Seems like something the `data.table`package might be well suited for? I know its syntax is well suited for these kinds of conditional modifications.

Comment: When `$Status == "No"`, to what field are you comparing `Sys.Date()`? Similarly, where do you define `DATE`?

Comment: @r2evans, my bad, I fixed the question now. `Status == "No"` compare Sys.Date() with date in Date column and chose weight that is closest to the Sys.Date() in this example, `12/17/2008` so the New_Weight is `134.12`

Comment: I got your code to work as desired, but (1) strings as Dates are problematic, so I converted with `mutate(Date=as.POSIXct(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y", tz="UTC"), Baseline=<similar>)`, and (2) replaced `DATE` with `Date`. If you are getting inconsistent results, provide an example of how it changes. (BTW: if your `Date`s are factors then this won't do what you want either, though you should be getting warnings to that effect.)

Comment: @r2evans, yes date should be in date format for this work you are right there but the results I am seeing are inconsistent in a sense that I need to run this once and shutdown RStudio and start again, if I run this multiple times in one session then from the second iteration onwards i keep seeing everything (New_Weight) as 134.12...it dont change according tot the `Status=="Yes"` and Baseline date criteria. I like to see this done in data.table like @Alex suggested above.

Comment: Which `Baseline` dates do you mean to use, the first table or second? They're different.

Comment: @r2evans, fixed that now :) both should be the same.

Comment: BTW: change my previous comment, it should be using `as.Date`, not `as.POSIXct`. I still get your desired output, no matter how many times I run it. Assuming you have `dplyr-0.4.3`, do you have any global variables that are named the same as any of these columns?

Comment: Are there any other calculations working here? Because you don't `ungroup()`, any other dplyr-based functions after this will by default use the grouping until you remove it. (Unless I intentionally need it, I tend to *always* remove a grouping at the end of a dplyr pipe.)

Comment: @r2evans, that is not an issue.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible given the data and dplyr-pipe you've presented. I'm not `data.table`-savvy, if you are wanting to go in that direction. Because of these, I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: @r2evans, no problem thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data <- fread(
"Id     Weight     Date         Status     Baseline
5      121.23     04/16/1995   No         NA
5      134.12     12/17/2008   No         NA
5      167.63     03/15/2002   No         NA
5      139.22     08/15/2001   No         NA
23     232.19     11/10/2009   Yes        11/06/2001
23     274.13     10/03/2004   Yes        11/06/2001
23     134.23     07/11/2006   Yes        11/06/2001"
) %>% mutate(
  Status   = Status=='Yes',
  Date     = as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"),
  Baseline = as.Date(Baseline, format="%m/%d/%Y")
)

data[, Recent_Weight := ifelse(Status,
  Weight[which.min(abs(Date-Baseline))],
  Weight[which.max(Date)] # no need to compare to Sys.Date()
                          # if you do not have dates in the future
), by=Id]
```

Comment: right on the money, that is so much better than using dplyr and mutate. +10 man.